# keep format of number and decimal but remove everything else

Tags: php, numbers, preg-match

I have a input fields for state and local tax.

Each field data is entered then I add both together to get totaltax.

I have tried number_format and round and print_f but none of them are working as I need them to.  I was trying to find a preg_match possibility.

What I need is, the input fields will take stuff like:

```
10.2
10.33
10.301
3.275
2.90
```

If someone enters .10 it should convert to 0.10.  If they enter 0.10 it should leave it alone.  Same for .125 should enter as 0.125

If it is not a number or a decimal it needs to be removed.

```
$statetax = $_POST['statetax']; 
$localtax = $_POST['localtax'];
$totaltax = $statetax+$localtax;

insert into tax (state, local, total) values($state, $local, $total)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

this is what i ended up using.

```
$statetax = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", "",$_POST['statetax']);
$localtax = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", "",$_POST['localtax']);
$totaltax = ($statetax+$localtax);
```

thanks everyone for chiming in.

Comment: The escape character for the period is unnecessary. This can be simplified to `$statetax = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "",$_POST['statetax']);`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to make sure that your input is a number. Then convert to a float and back to a string to get sure a `0` will be prepened if required. This uses [`floatval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) and [`strval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php)

I hope the following example helps:

```
$tests = array(
    '10.2',
    '10.33',
    '.301',
    'bar',
    '3.275',
    '2.90',
    '.1',
    'foo'
);

foreach($tests as $input) {
    // check if the value is number using `is_numeric`
    if(!is_numeric($input)) {
        echo "Error: Not a number: $input\n";
        continue;
    }   

    // convert to float and back to string ( in the echo ) will 
    // automatically prepend a 0 if required
    $sanitizedInput = strval(floatval($input));
    echo "Sanitized input: $sanitizedInput\n";
}
```

Comment: This is not working as I needed it to, if I change the first value of 10.2 to 10.2% or $10.2 it errors.  I don't want it to error but rather strip the $ or % or any other character that is not a number or decimal.

Comment: What if input is `10.2%10.1` ? Use the first value?

Comment: Input would not be entered as 10.2%10.1. It would be entered as 10.2% or $10.50.  but I wanted to just have something rock solid that would strip ALL characters but leave numbers and dots(periods) alone.  I found this preg_match that I am playing with now: preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", "",$statetax);

Comment: `Input would not be entered as 10.2%10.1.`.. You cannot say this if input comes from the web. Note that input can be *everything*. Having this string your regex would fail. I'm preparing some preg_* related stuff too. will post if ready

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$statetax = (float) is_numeric($_POST['statetax']) ? $_POST['statetax'] : 0;
$localtax = (float) is_numeric($_POST['localtax']) ? $_POST['localtax'] : 0;
$totaltax = $statetax + $localtax;

mysql_query(
    "insert into tax ('state', 'local', 'total') values($statetax, $localtax, $totaltax)"
);
```

In general its a good idea to escape user input ($_POST, ...) when building an SQL string. Otherwise you are setting yourself up for SQL injection. Have a read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). In this case its not necessary as the float typecasting makes sure your POST values are "escaped".

Comment: I will try this, thanks. I am escaping but in the example I kept everything simple to get function.  :)

Comment: Problem with this is, I don't want it to error out if it has a number such as 10.3% or $10.50 - I am looking for it to strip everything but leave the numbers and decimals where they are.  Then if the number starts with a decimal to add a zero it it.  So if it starts with .50 to format it as 0.50   - thanks!

Comment: You can try to filter the post data first by running it through preg_replace: `$_POST['statetax'] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]\./', '',  $_POST['statetax']);`. This strips everything but numbers and ".".